# USQL Performance Issue

Tags: u-sql

I have written usql scripts which basically extract certain fields from JSONs, merges them and write into csv format.
The issue is the folder where jsons are present contains only json files not any other file, the total size of the single folder is 19GB I triggered the batch using 20 AU and its more than 2 hrs still in running state with 0% progress.
It also not throwing any error message.
Any idea what is the issue.

Comment: Would it be possible to share some code. It would be difficult to suggest things to try out from the description of your question

Comment: Also if you post the JOB graph in some shape or form, that would be great to figure out.